# Last Bar overlap with Right YAxis d3js

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I follow https://bl.ocks.org/nanu146/f48ffc5ec10270f55c9e1fb3da8b38f0 and http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579 and make a Bar Graph with line an tooltip

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    body {
        font: 10px sans-serif;
    }

    .axis path,
    .axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    .bar {
        fill: orange;
    }
    .bar:hover {
  fill: orangered ;
}


    .x.axis path {
        display: none;
    }
    .d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
</style>
<body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
    <div>
        <svg id="graph"></svg>
    </div>
    <script>
//https://bl.ocks.org/nanu146/f48ffc5ec10270f55c9e1fb3da8b38f0
    function getTextWidth(text, fontSize, fontName) {
            c = document.createElement("canvas");
            ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.font = fontSize + ' ' + fontName;
            return ctx.measureText(text).width;
        }

        function DataSegregator(array, on) {
            var SegData;
            OrdinalPositionHolder = {
                valueOf: function () {
                    thisObject = this;
                    keys = Object.keys(thisObject);
                    keys.splice(keys.indexOf("valueOf"), 1);
                    keys.splice(keys.indexOf("keys"), 1);
                    return keys.length == 0 ? -1 : d3.max(keys, function (d) { return thisObject[d] })
                }
                , keys: function () {
                    keys = Object.keys(thisObject);
                    keys.splice(keys.indexOf("valueOf"), 1);
                    keys.splice(keys.indexOf("keys"), 1);
                    return keys;
                }
            }
            array[0].map(function (d) { return d[on] }).forEach(function (b) {
                value = OrdinalPositionHolder.valueOf();
                OrdinalPositionHolder[b] = OrdinalPositionHolder > -1 ? ++value : 0;
            })

            SegData = OrdinalPositionHolder.keys().map(function () {
                return [];
            });

            array.forEach(function (d) {
                d.forEach(function (b) {
                    SegData[OrdinalPositionHolder[b[on]]].push(b);
                })
            });

            return SegData;
        }

        Data = [
{ Date: "1", Categories: [{ Name: "Test  Exam Jan", Value: 10 }], LineCategory: [{ Name: "Line1", Value: 69 }] },
{ Date: "2", Categories: [{ Name: "Test  Exam Feb", Value: 1 }], LineCategory: [{ Name: "Line1", Value: 89 }] },
{ Date: "3", Categories: [{ Name: "Test  Exam March", Value: 1 }], LineCategory: [{ Name: "Line1", Value: 72 }] },
{ Date: "4", Categories: [{ Name: "Test  Exam 1", Value: 1 }], LineCategory: [{ Name: "Line1", Value: 75 }] },
{ Date: "5", Categories: [{ Name: "Test  Exam 2", Value: 5 }], LineCategory: [{ Name: "Line1", Value: 52 }] },
{ Date: "6", Categories: [{ Name: "Test  Exam 3", Value: 3 }], LineCategory: [{ Name: "Line1", Value: 40 }] },
{ Date: "7", Categories: [{ Name: "Test  Exam 4", Value: 12 }], LineCategory: [{ Name: "Line1", Value: 37 }] },
{ Date: "8", Categories: [{ Name: "Test  Exam 5", Value: 5 }], LineCategory: [{ Name: "Line1", Value: 68 }] },
{ Date: "9", Categories: [{ Name: "Test  Exam 6", Value: 3 }], LineCategory: [{ Name: "Line1", Value: 92 }] },
{ Date: "10", Categories: [{ Name: "Test  Exam 7", Value: 7 }], LineCategory: [{ Name: "Line1", Value: 95 }] },
{ Date: "11", Categories: [{ Name: "Test  Exam 8", Value: 2 }], LineCategory: [{ Name: "Line1", Value: 55 }] },
{ Date: "12", Categories: [{ Name: "Test  Exam 9", Value: 9 }], LineCategory: [{ Name: "Line1", Value: 50 }] },
{ Date: "13", Categories: [{ Name: "Test  Exam 10",Value: 1 }], LineCategory: [{ Name: "Line1", Value: 25 }] },
{ Date: "14", Categories: [{ Name: "Test  Exam 11",Value: 4 }], LineCategory: [{ Name: "Line1", Value: 99 }] },
{ Date: "15", Categories: [{ Name: "Test  Exam 12",Value: 7 }], LineCategory: [{ Name: "Line1", Value: 82 }] },
{ Date: "16", Categories: [{ Name: "Test  Exam 13",Value: 5 }], LineCategory: [{ Name: "Line1", Value: 32 }] },
    ]



        var margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 60, left: 40 },
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var textWidthHolder = 0;
        /// Adding Date in LineCategory
        Data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.LineCategory.forEach(function (b) {
                b.Date = d.Date;
            })
        });




        var Categories = new Array();
        // Extension method declaration

        Categories.pro

        var Data;
        var ageNames;
        var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0, width],.1);
        var XLine = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundPoints([0, width], .5);
        var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([height, 0]);

        var YLine = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0])
        .domain([0, d3.max(Data, function (d) { return d3.max(d.LineCategory, function (b) { return b.Value }) })]);

        /*var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);*/

        var line = d3.svg.line().x(function (d) {
            return x0(d.Date) + x0.rangeBand() / 2;
        }).y(function (d) { return YLine(d.Value) });




        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(x0)
            .orient("bottom");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .scale(y)
            .orient("left")
            .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

        var YLeftAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(YLine).orient("right").tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));
console.log(YLeftAxis)
        var svg = d3.select("#graph")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Frequency:</strong> <span style='color:red'>Test</span>";
  })

svg.call(tip);


        // Bar Data categories
        Data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.Categories.forEach(function (b) {
                if (Categories.findIndex(function (c) { return c.Name===b.Name}) == -1) {
                    b.Type = "bar";
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(b))
                    Categories.push(b)
                }
            })
        });


        // Line Data categories
        Data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.LineCategory.forEach(function (b) {
                if (Categories.findIndex(function (c) { return c.Name === b.Name }) == -1) {
                    b.Type = "line";
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(b))
                    Categories.push(b)
                }
            })
        });

        // Processing Line data
        lineData = DataSegregator(Data.map(function (d) { return d.LineCategory }), "Name");

        // Line Coloring
        LineColor = d3.scale.ordinal();
        LineColor.domain(Categories.filter(function (d) { return d.Type == "line" }).map(function (d) { return d.Name }));
        LineColor.range(["#d40606", "#06bf00", "#98bdc5", "#671919", "#0b172b"])
        x0.domain(Data.map(function (d) { return d.Date; }));
        XLine.domain(Data.map(function (d) { return d.Date; }));
        x1.domain(Categories.filter(function (d) { return d.Type == "bar" }).map(function (d) { return d.Name})).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
        y.domain([0, d3.max(Data, function (d) { return d3.max(d.Categories, function (d) { return d.Value; }); })]);

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append("g")
           .attr("class", "y axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width) + ",0)")
           .call(YLeftAxis)
           .append("text")
           .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
           .attr("y", -10)
           .attr("dy", ".71em")
           .style("text-anchor", "end")
           .text("Percent");

        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis)
          .append("text")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", ".71em")
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .text("Population");


        var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
            .data(Data)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "state")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.Date) + ",0)"; });

        state.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(function (d) { return d.Categories; })
            .enter().append("rect")
            //.attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("width", x0.rangeBand())
            .attr("x", function (d) { return x1(d.Name); })
            .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.Value); })
            .attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.Value); })
            //.style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.Name); })
            .on("click",function(d){console.log(d)})
            .on('mouseover', tip.show)
            .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
            .transition().delay(500).attrTween("height", function (d) {
                var i = d3.interpolate(0, height - y(d.Value));
                return function (t)
                {
                    return i(t);
                }
            });



        // drawaing lines
        svg.selectAll(".lines").data(lineData).enter().append("g").attr("class", "line")
        .each(function (d) {
            Name=d[0].Name
            d3.select(this).append("path").attr("d", function (b) { return line(b) }).style({ "stroke-width": "2px", "fill": "none" }).style("stroke", LineColor(Name)).transition().duration(1500);
        })


        // Legends

       /* var LegendHolder = svg.append("g").attr("class", "legendHolder");
        var legend = LegendHolder.selectAll(".legend")
            .data(Categories.map(function (d) { return {"Name":d.Name,"Type":d.Type}}))
          .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(0," +( height+ margin.bottom/2 )+ ")"; })
            .each(function (d,i) {
                //  Legend Symbols


                d3.select(this).append("rect")
                .attr("width", function () { return 18 })
                .attr("x", function (b) {

                    left = (i+1) * 15 + i * 18 + i * 5 + textWidthHolder;
                    return left;
                })
                 .attr("y", function (b) { return b.Type == 'bar'?0:7})
                .attr("height", function (b) { return b.Type== 'bar'? 18:5 })
                .style("fill", function (b) { return b.Type == 'bar' ? color(d.Name) : LineColor(d.Name) });

                //  Legend Text

                d3.select(this).append("text")
                .attr("x", function (b) {

                    left = (i+1) * 15 + (i+1) * 18 + (i + 1) * 5 + textWidthHolder;

                    return left;
                })
                .attr("y", 9)
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .style("text-anchor", "start")
                .text(d.Name);

                textWidthHolder += getTextWidth(d.Name, "10px", "calibri");
            })
            ;*/


        // Legend Placing

        d3.select(".legendHolder").attr("transform", function (d) {
            thisWidth = d3.select(this).node().getBBox().width;
            return "translate(" + ((width) / 2 - thisWidth / 2) + ",0)";
        })


    </script>
</body>
```

If you run above code you will see a barchart like bellow image

[image]

the problem is last bar overlap with right axis .which I unable to fix .
any body have any suggestion to fix .please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not correctly positioning your bars regarding the x coordinate.

Since your groups are already translated...

```
.attr("transform", function (d) { 
    return "translate(" + x0(d.Date) + ",0)"; 
});
```

... this line:

```
.attr("x", function (d) { return x1(d.Name); })
```

Should be simply:

```
.attr("x", 0)
```

Here is a fiddle with that change only: https://jsfiddle.net/6gpwmups/

Comment: Is there any way to add pointer on line like http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/a22c42db65eb00d4e369